# Change fadeAnimation option after creation of the map

Tags: leaflet

I know how to set fadeAnimation to false at the creation of a map :

```
map = L.map('map', {
  fadeAnimation:false
});
```

But I'm looking for a way to set fadeAnimation true or false, on demand, AFTER the creation of the map.

`map.options.fadeAnimation = false` doesn't work.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `_fadeAnimated` property:

```
map._fadeAnimated = false
```